# Is it possible to have buffers in layers?

Tags: display

In Emacs, can you get something like the following:

```
10 |int foo() {
11 |    int a = bar();
12 | 30 |int bar() {
13 | 31 |    return 10; 
14 | 32 |}
15 | // Bar.h
// Foo.c
```

The idea is that instead of going to the definition, the definition is spliced in at the point. This would be very similar to the ["Peek definition"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-and-edit-code-by-using-peek-definition-alt-plus-f12?view=vs-2017) feature in Visual Studio 2017.

Is it even possible to "layer" a buffer on top of another buffer like this? Further, is it possible to get viewport-style scrolling inside the "top layer" buffer (like an ordinary buffer)? If it is possible to do so, please attach a screenshot of the result in your answer.

I've tried searching for related terms but I've only bumped into (a) indirect buffers -- these don't seem to be what I'm looking for and (b) [overlays](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html) -- these seem to be modifying the view of the current buffer, not putting in a new buffer.

To be clear, I don't want to open another pane by splitting the window; I know that is already possible today.

Comment: I don't have an answer but, IIRC, GUI tooltips are actually graphical frames, in which case I don't see why that same general mechanism couldn't achieve what you want, in principle.  If you wanted to dig into that code, see `tooltip.el`.

Comment: See [this](http://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-frame-peek.html)

Comment: You can try [`(info "(elisp) Child Frames")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Child-Frames.html), see also http://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-frame-peek.html